# Copying python scripts into docker container in sagemaker

Tags: python, docker, jupyter, amazon-sagemaker

I have been frustrated by this copy error while trying to copy a python script to docker container. I am doing this in AWS Sagemaker. Anyone can suggest why this error happens.
The train_sm.py code I am trying to copy is inside the src folder. The dockerfile is inside the docker folder.

What is the build context here?
I also tried moving the .py scripts inside the docker folder, and it still same error.
This seems small problem, but has taken my whole day. I
Any help and hints are appreciated.
I have attached a screenshot of codes, folder structures and error.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Does it help to cd into the folder before running build I wonder? e.g. `!cd docker && docker build .` (can't run as two separate `!` commands as the working dir will be reverted)

Comment: !cd docker &&  ...  didn't help.

Comment: Would it be suitable to just move the file into the docker folder (same directory as the Dockerfile)?

Comment: Replying back, cd docker seems to help, but also needed some chmod +x operations on certain files inside the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion to structure your file structure as follows;

```
Project
 -Dockerfile
 -src
    -a.py
    -b.py
    -c.py
 -packages
sagemaker_script.py
build_push_script.sh
Data
 -train
 -test
 -validate
```

Then you can run from the Project with a command like `docker ... Dockerfile`
and inside the Dockerfile you can simply put `COPY ./src/* /opt/ml/code/`

Comment: Adding few !Chmod line helped!